# How to convert server time to device default time zone?

Tags: android

I am posting date to server from my device.
My device date time is `2014-08-22 11:11:00` when I insert date and time in to server, but when I get date and time from the server it returns `2014-08-21 23:41:00`.
So how can I convert server time  "`2014-08-21 23:41:00`" to my device time "`2014-08-22 11:11:00`"?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what is your timeZone? and the server? also post some code

Comment: try using timestamp and do the conversion at runtime.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin my timeZome is GMT +05:30.

Comment: Convert your time to UTC before sending it to the server, have the server store the UTC time and return it when requested. Then, on the device, you can re-convert the UTC time from the server to your local timezone.

Comment: I got the answer from here
http://javagrip.blogspot.in/2012/09/date-from-one-timezone-to-another-in-java.html